# golang - how to list excel spreadsheet column names?

Tags: excel, go

golang - how to list excel column names ??
[image]

As shown in image , the exel columns are listed as A B C ... AA AB AC .... There is no sample available on how to list this in go lang. This is needed when parsing excel spreadsheet to get range of spreadsheet tabs to get cells values

Comment: you can use Excelize package there is so many functions like:  ColumnNumberToName(num int) (string, error)As an example : excelize.ColumnNumberToName(37) // returns "AK",

Answer (score 3):

Here is an efficient solution.

```
func getColumnName(col int) string {
    name := make([]byte, 0, 3) // max 16,384 columns (2022)
    const aLen = 'Z' - 'A' + 1 // alphabet length
    for ; col > 0; col /= aLen + 1 {
        name = append(name, byte('A'+(col-1)%aLen))
    }
    for i, j := 0, len(name)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        name[i], name[j] = name[j], name[i]
    }
    return string(name)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/upjBQeE1x8I

---

The OP (@mahbh2001) posted an answer to his own question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71350368

Here are the results of `getColumnName` benchmarks for columns 1 through 99:

```
rocka2q:
BenchmarkA2Q-4  758865  1498 ns/op   146 B/op   73 allocs/op

OP (mahbh2001):
BenchmarkOP-4   122714  9515 ns/op  1376 B/op  341 allocs/op
```

The OP's code is significantly slower.

Comment: does not work for col = 53 and so on

Answer (score 2):

I tried to search for handy function to get excel column names but was not able to get in golang , so created one , hope this helps other to save time

```
package main

import "fmt"

func reverse(s string) string {
    runes := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(runes)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        runes[i], runes[j] = runes[j], runes[i]
    }
    return string(runes)
}

// Function to print Excel column
// name for a given column number
//
func getColumnName(columnNumber int) string {

    // To store result (Excel column name)
    var columnName = ""
    for ok := true; ok; ok = columnNumber > 0 {

        // Find remainder
        rem := columnNumber % 26

        // If remainder is 0, then a
        // 'Z' must be there in output
        if rem == 0 {
            columnName += "Z"
            columnNumber = (columnNumber / 26) - 1
        } else // If remainder is non-zero
        {
            columnName += string((rem - 1) + int('A'))
            columnNumber = columnNumber / 26
        }
    }

    // Reverse the string
    columnName = reverse(columnName)
    return columnName

}

func main() {
    for cm := 1; cm < 100; cm++ {
        fmt.Println(getColumnName(cm))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one with an error handler.
this is modified from [excelize](https://github.com/qax-os/excelize/blob/f0cb29cf6668ab96992b1e48278d9f5b1f9e4976/lib.go#L217)
note that this is not as fast as @rocka2q answer.

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    for cm := 1; cm < 100; cm++ {
        cmName, _ := ColumnNumberToName(cm)
        fmt.Println(cmName)
    }

}

func ColumnNumberToName(num int) (string, error) {
    if num < 1 {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("incorrect column number %d", num)
    }
    if num > 16384 {
        return "", errors.New("column number exceeds maximum limit")
    }
    var col string
    for num > 0 {
        col = string(rune((num-1)%26+65)) + col
        num = (num - 1) / 26
    }
    return col, nil
}
```

or you can directly use the excelize function:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/xuri/excelize/v2"
)

func main() {

    for cm := 1; cm < 100; cm++ {
        cmName, _ := excelize.ColumnNumberToName(cm)
        fmt.Println(cmName)
    }

}
```